# Input 0 of layer "model" is incompatible with the layer: expected shape=(None, 250, 3), found shape=(None, 3) in trained transformer model

Tags: numpy, tensorflow, tf.keras, transformer-model, attention-model

I have a keras `transformer` model trained with tensorflow `2.7.0` and python `3.7` with input shape: `(None, 250, 3)` and a 2D array input with shape: `(250, 3)`(not an image)

When making a prediction with:

`prediction = model.predict(state)`

I get `ValueError: Input 0 of layer "model" is incompatible with the layer: expected shape=(None, 250, 3), found shape=(None, 3)`

project code: https://github.com/MikeSifanele/TT

This is how `state` looks like:

`state = np.array([[-0.07714844,-0.06640625,-0.140625],[-0.140625,-0.1650391,-0.2265625]...[0.6376953,0.6005859,0.6083984],[0.7714844,0.7441406,0.7578125]], np.float32)`

Comment: Could you share any code?

Comment: @paul-shuvo I've uploaded the project

Comment: Could you try adding a new axis like `state = np.expand_dims(state, axis=0)` and run the code and see if that works?

Comment: Please trim your code to make it easier to find your problem. Follow these guidelines to create a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Some explanation:

For input shape to the model i.e. `(None, 250, 3)`, the first axis (represented by `None`) is the "sample" axis, while the rest i.e. `250,3` denotes the input dimension. Thus, when the input shape is `(250, 3)` it assumes the first axis as the "sample" axis and the rest as the input dimension i.e. just `3`. So, to make it consistent we need to add a dimension at the beginning described in the following:

```py
state = np.expand_dims(state, axis=0)
```

The shape of `state` then becomes `(1, 250, 3)` ~`(None, 250, 3)`.